# How do I stop NGINX from sending through the identifying part of the URL?

Tags: nginx, prometheus, grafana

I'm setting up an AWS instance to house both my prometheus and grafana servers. I'm using NGINX to route between the 2 clients through a /location. The problem is, NGINX has to pass this value through, and the clients can't make sense of it.

My NGINX config:

```
http {
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
server_names_hash_bucket_size  128;
types_hash_max_size 4096;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name <aws instance url>;
    location /grafana {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
    location /prometheus {
            allow <my ip>;
            deny all;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9090;
    }
}

}
```

So when I navigate to /grafana. It successfully takes me to grafana, but the grafana client attempts to parse the /grafana and can't find a page for it, and returns a 404.

Is there a way to get rid of that, or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: What you need is the trailing / check this https://serverfault.com/questions/562756/how-to-remove-the-path-with-an-nginx-proxy-pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out between these 2 solutions that just allow prometheus and grafana to be run behind a sub-path, so nginx can just pass it through normally:

For prometheus, launching it with the `--web.external-url=/prometheus/` flag set:
https://blog.cubieserver.de/2020/configure-prometheus-on-a-sub-path-behind-reverse-proxy/

For Grafana, setting the server.root_url in the config:
https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/#1

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to preserve the rest of the URI after `/grafana` and `/prometheus`?

If yes, then you need to rewrite the URI:

```
server {
    ...
    location /grafana {
        rewrite ^/grafana(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
    location /prometheus {
        allow <my ip>;
        deny all;
        rewrite ^/prometheus(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9090;
    }
}
```

You may consult [the documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) on the `ngx_http_rewrite_module` for more information about the `rewrite` directive and its parameters.

If not, then simply put:

```
server {
    ...
    location /grafana {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/; # Note the trailing slash here...
    }
    location /prometheus {
        allow <my ip>;
        deny all;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9090/; # ...and here
    }
}
```

Comment: While trying to "preserve the uri" (The 2nd solution doesn't work, because the whole client isn't served, when prometheus directs to it's /graph page, it throws a 404 because nginx doesn't know to look at prometheus for it). I think the first fix would take care of this, but I get a 500 error that the URI has a zero length